# Autohotkey Open Run Dialog and execute command

Tags: autohotkey

I currently would like autohotkey to open the run dialog box, then focus on the box and enter a command to run Excel in its own instance.  The issue I have I only know how to send key, but that isn't very reliable as if my computer lags it won't capture the text.  Is there anyway to focus the dialog box and have text placed into it then ran?

```
^+e::
    SetKeyDelay, 0
    FileDlg := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").FileRun, FileDlg := ""
    send, excel.exe /x {ENTER}
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use COM directly on Excel

```
xl := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")         ; createa a handle to excel file
xl.Workbooks.Add                                ; create new workbook
xl.Visible := True                              ; set Excel to be visible
```

Comment: Sweet - I thought I had to go with the Run Command to open a new instance. This works great. Thank you!

Comment: I just realized that my Personal Workbook doesn't load launching this way. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @Snoobie, find the path to your Personal Workbook i.e. `mypath := "C:\Users\alpha.bravo\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\Excel15.xlb"`, then add this line to the code above `xl.Workbooks.Open(mypath)`